# Nginx proxy pass regex

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx as a reverse proxy while using regex at the same time. I want this URI on my server:
[www.mydomain.com/dealers/in/evansville/11487/](http://www.mydomain.com/dealers/in/evansville/11487/)

To proxy this to the remote server:
locations.where2getit.com/mydomain/in/evansville/11487/

When I use the location rule below, I'm getting a 502 error:

```
location ~* (.*dealers)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ {
    proxy_pass https://locations.where2getit.com/mydomain/$2/$3/$4/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}
```

Any tips to get this working properly?

Comment: Check the nginx error log.

Comment: All I have is:
```2021/07/16 11:07:34 [notice] 608950#608950: signal process started
2021/07/16 11:07:46 [notice] 609223#609223: signal process started```

Comment: Adding a resolver and stripping down some of headers seems to be an improvement.
```location ~* (.*dealers)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://locations.where2getit.com/mydomain/$2/$3/$4;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}```